# php thread safety of using static class members as super global variable

Tags: php, thread-safety, mutex, static-members, superglobals

I want to have my own super global variables accessible from all of my scripts and I'm using static class members to achieve this but I'm concerned that as the php server creates a separate thread for each script file and in some of my scripts I'm reading or modifying this variables should the critical sections of my code be protected with mutex locks?

### example of usage

SuperGlobals.php

```
class MySuperGlobals {
      public static $Variables=array("visited"=>array());

     }
```

---

index.php

```
<?php

   include "SuperGlobals.php";
   array_push(MySuperGlobals::$Variables["visited"] ,"index");
   echo MySuperGlobals::$Variables["visited"][count(MySuperGlobals::$Variables["visited"])-1];//last element

?>
```

---

page1.php

```
<?php
    include "SuperGlobals.php";
    array_push(MySuperGlobals::$Variables["visited"] ,"page1");
    echo MySuperGlobals::$Variables["visited"][count(MySuperGlobals::$Variables["visited"])-1];//last element
?>
```

in the example above is array_push alone thread safe for the static member(ignoring the echo's )and how about the whole push and echo if we want to protect it what should be done? should I create a static mutex object in the class and lock and unlock these lines?

Comment: I dont think so, because requests are not multi-threded, nor is Apache in the context of a request.  Two requests don't know anything about each other.  But if you wanted a locking script I just so happen to have one [here](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/ProcLock.php).  I use it mainly for cron initiated background workers, but whatever.

Comment: Although a variable will be available to all scripts, when your talking about all scripts running on different pages by a different request you will have to look into something like a shared cache or use a database table.  Values aren't shared between requests.  Think about why people use sessions.

Comment: @NigelRen - I was thinking the same thing like Redis.